# URI rewriting add unwanted context path

Tags: url, jakarta-ee, forward

I have my app to find resource at

```
http://myhost/my-app/test/bat
```

and it works good, now have this a new request to

```
http://myhost/my-app/xxx/test/bat,
```

I simply want it rewrited to the old one, so I creat a filter:

> ```
> if(uri.endsWith("/xxx/test/bat")){
>      uri=uri.replace("/xxx/test", "/test");
>      request.getRequestDispatcher(uri).forward(req, res);
>   }
>  else
>      chain.doFilter(req, res);
> ```

but the tomcat container rewrite the url to:

```
http://myhost/my-app/my-app/test/bat
```

/my-app is the contextPath

why I got this extra my-app? where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you getting your uri value? what is it's value? I suspect it might be "/my-app/xxx/test/bat". When you use request.getRequestDispatcher if the path begins with a "/" it is interpreted as relative to the current context root.

Comment: you're right! I use request.getRequestURI() and get "/my-app/xxx/test/bat". I changed the param to "/test/bat", it works now. thanks!